# Same-site cookie settings and cookies with FQDN

Tags: asp.net, cookies, web-config, session-cookies, samesite

api.myweb.com and myweb.com will share the cookie default.

(If I misunderstand, please let me know)

If I set the cookies with same-site attributes in web config,

such as `<sessionState  cookieSameSite="Strict"/>`

does it solve the **Loosely Scoped Cookie**(FQDN low vulnerability problem)

happen as above? Or are they non-related problems?

Thanks!

Comment: ...why are you still using WebForms in 2023?

Comment: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/223473/for-samesite-cookie-with-subdomains-what-are-considered-the-same-site

Comment: The `SameSite` cookie attribute is _more_ concerned with _unsafe_ cross-origin requests (such as Website1.com having an embedded cross-origin POSTed form, such as `<form method="post" action="https://website2.com>`  rather than the (decreasingly relevant) Cookie `Domain=` binding, [though it does impact that too](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie/SameSite))

Comment: @Dai  Thank you the information.So api.myweb.com and myweb.com is the same -site.(If myweb.com is not register in the public suffix list the information the hyperlink mentions to) I still add the domain atrribute to solve the issue.Or is it necessary highly concerned to the Loosely Scoped Cookie problems?

Comment: It depends on your application - I can't say based on the limited information you've posted.